# Only one button working despite formaction

Tags: php, html

I have a file.php that is echoing the contents of a html file. The solution to my problem seems to be to use formaction according to stackoverflow but for some reason I can't get it to work. 'Createuser' works but not 'shop'. I have tried with not having formaction on the 'shop' button as well since I already have action = shop but it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
<form method="post" action="shop.php"> 
      <table>
      <p>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="sign_in" form method="post" formaction="shop.php"/>
        <input type="submit" value="Create user" name="create_user" formaction="createuser.php" />
        </table>
      </p>
    </form>
```

Comment: tried writing `formmethod` instead of `form method` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first button shouldn't need formaction as it is defined in the form properties.

Could you try changing your inputs to buttons? something like.

```
<button type="submit" formaction="createuser.php">Create User</button>
```

It is important to use type="submit" here or formaction will be ignored.

Comment: Thanks, worked great. Will accept as answer in a few minutes when I'm allowed to

Comment: Glad it helped!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the form action, form and method attributes from the sign in submit input. I know you said you removed formaction, but I think the below should work.

```
<input type="submit" value="Sign in" name="sign_in" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but where you have your closing table tag isn't where it should be this:

```
<form method="post" action="shop.php"> 
  <table>
      <p>
        <input type="button" value="Sign in" name="sign_in" form method="post" formaction="shop.php"/>
        <input type="button" value="Create user" name="create_user" formaction="createuser.php" />
      </p>
  </table>
</form>
```